# Upload avatar after account activation (buddypress)

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Here is what I'm am trying to do.

1. User registers on the homepage.
2. User is redirected to the check email for activation page.
3. User clicks activation link.
4. User is redirected to the activation success page.

On step 4, I'm either trying to add a 5th step redirecting to a custom avatar upload page.

I know how to redirect to a page but I have no idea what code to copy over from BuddyPress to that blank page.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?